# Sqoop - changing a Hive column data type to Postgres data type

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I'm trying to change the last column of the hive table (which is type `STRING` in hive) to a Postgres type `date` below is the command:

```
sqoop export 
--connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.11.1:5432/test 
--username test 
--password test_password 
--table posgres_table 
--hcatalog-database hive_db 
--hcatalog-table hive_table
```

I have tried using, this but the column in Postgres is still empty:

> -map-column-hive batch_date=date

Answer (score 0):

`-map-column-hive` works only for Sqoop import (i.e. while fetching data from RDBMS to HDFS/Hive)

All you need to make your Hive's String data in proper date format, it should work.

Internally, sqoop export create statements like

`INSERT INTO posgres_table...`

You can verify by manually creating `INSERT INTO posgres_table values(...)` statment via JDBC driver or any client like **pgAdmin**, **squirrel-sql**, etc.